# Powershell Regex Content and Write back

Tags: regex, powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write a part of a script that replaces a match line with RegEx.

Here's what the input looks like:

```
Name, type, ADDRESSES
“Aaa”, “bbb”, “19 S 149TH $NEWPORT NEWS, WA 96332”
“Aaa”, “bbb”,  “851 16TH AVE #365$SALISH, WA 98402-4410”
“Aaa”, “bbb”,  “2445 E BROADWAY #204$YELM WA 98653”
```

Here's what I've tried

```
$regex = '\d{5}([ \-]\d{4})?'

##get the data
$people = Get-Content 'C:\test.csv'

## let's convert the data first

foreach ($p in $people) {
    if ($p -match $regex) { $p | out-file -append C:\test.csv }
}
```

Here's what I expect back

```
Name, type, ADDRESSES
“Aaa”, “bbb”,  “96332”
“Aaa”, “bbb”,  “98402-4410”
“Aaa”, “bbb”,  “98653”
```

Here's what I get back:

```
Name, type, ADDRESSES
“Aaa”, “bbb”, “19 S 149TH $NEWPORT NEWS, WA 96332”
“Aaa”, “bbb”,  “851 16TH AVE #365$SALISH, WA 98402-4410”
“Aaa”, “bbb”,  “2445 E BROADWAY #204$YELM WA 98653”
```

Comment: In addition to Olaf's comment which I assume is just a typo, `$p -match $regex` is just going to check if the line matches and then you output the whole line (`$p`) to file as-is.  You are not manipulating the line first.

Comment: I fixed the code.

Comment: The csv data now does not "pass validation" because you have commas in the ADDRESSES column.  You would need to surround your addresses with quotes so that they are properly parsed as a single column when using `Import-Csv` OR if you stick with `Get-Content` then you need to update your regex and use `-Replace`

Comment: Like import-csv and the change the $_.ADDRESSES ?

Answer (score 1):

This *should* work.

```
$text = @'
Name, type, ADDRESSES
Aaa, bbb, 19 S 149TH $NEWPORT NEWS, WA 96332
Aaa, bbb,  851 16TH AVE #365$SALISH, WA 98402-4410
Aaa, bbb,  2445 E BROADWAY #204$YELM WA 98653
'@ -split '\r?\n' | Select-Object -Skip 1

$result = $text.ForEach({
    $name, $type, $addresses = $_.Split(',',3)
    $addresses = [regex]::Matches($addresses, '[\d-]+(?=$)').Value

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $name
        Type = $type
        Addresses = $addresses
    }
})
```

```
Name Type Addresses 
---- ---- --------- 
Aaa   bbb 96332     
Aaa   bbb 98402-4410
Aaa   bbb 98653
```

Comment: Ok, or you can just do this. My regex is more fun though. :)

Comment: @Daniel I think I didn't understood the concept lol, just posted for fun. I didn't expect OP to provide much feedback given he didn't accept any of his previous questions hehe

Comment: @Daniel `[regex]::Matches($addresses,'(?<=WA).+$').Value.Trim()` should do it too assuming all lines have `WA` no? I wanna get better at regex, it's so fun :P

Comment: It would work, but not for all.  You're open to false matches, like the 'WA' in 'BROADWAY'.   https://regex101.com/r/7TpOlc/1  The version in your answer works perfect.  I think your solution is better than mine and my crazy (unnecessary) regex lol.

Answer (score 1):

To continue from comments, since the csv data is not in good form it might be better to use a different regex and `-replace` to modify the data.

```
$file = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

# add test data to a file
@'
Name, type, ADDRESSES
Aaa, bbb, 19 S 149TH $NEWPORT NEWS, WA 96332
Aaa, bbb,  851 16TH AVE #365$SALISH, WA 98402-4410
Aaa, bbb,  2445 E BROADWAY #204$YELM WA 98653
'@ | Set-Content $file

$regex = ',[ \w$#]+,?[ \w]+(\d{5}(?:\-\d+)?)$'

# This line will read in the file, skipping the header line.
# Then it will perform a replace using the regex above 
# substituting whatever is matched with the first matching group (\d{5}(?:\-\d+).
# Finally the lines are appended to the end of the file
(Get-Content $file | Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace $regex, ', $1' | Add-Content -Path $file

# Get-Content to check our file
Get-Content $file
```

Output

```
Name, type, ADDRESSES
Aaa, bbb, 19 S 149TH $NEWPORT NEWS, WA 96332
Aaa, bbb,  851 16TH AVE #365$SALISH, WA 98402-4410
Aaa, bbb,  2445 E BROADWAY #204$YELM WA 98653
Aaa, bbb, 96332
Aaa, bbb, 98402-4410
Aaa, bbb, 98653
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.  Just replace everything up to 5 digits with only the 5 digits.  It still works if there's a 5 digit number in the beginning.  https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy

```
import-csv file.csv | 
  % { $_.addresses = $_.addresses -replace '.*(\d{5})', '$1'; $_ }
```

```
Name type ADDRESSES
---- ---- ---------
Aaa  bbb  96332
Aaa  bbb  98402-4410
Aaa  bbb  98653
```

Comment: This worked! Can you tell me how I can edit this to remove the -#### instead of capturing it?

Comment: Replace `'.*(\d{5}).*'` instead.

Comment: If there's an address like "12345 W Main St, BFE WA 98899-0023" will that capture the first group only?

Comment: Nope regex is greedy.

Comment: I googled that but i'm unsure what it means in this context. Can you elaborate? Is it greedy because it captures the final instance of the match or the largest number? I'm trying to test ways I can break the match with a poorly formatted address field.

Comment: Aww where's the fun in this regex?  :). Not sure what I was thinking with mine.  Guess I was trying to be extra cautious.  @Jacobyoby, the `.*` will consume everything only giving back the very minimum to make the match so it will only match on the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents on this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'theOriginal.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'ADDRESSES'; Expression = { $_.ADDRESSES -replace '.*\s([-\d]+)$', '$1'}} -ExcludeProperty ADDRESSES
}

# output on screen
$csv

# write to file
$csv | Export-Csv -Path 'theUpdated.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Result:

```
Name type ADDRESSES 
---- ---- --------- 
Aaa  bbb  96332     
Aaa  bbb  98402-4410
Aaa  bbb  98653
```

Regex details:

```
.             Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *          Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s            Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
(             Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [-\d]      Match a single character present in the list below
              The character “-”
              A single digit 0..9
      +       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)            
$             Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```